# Android custom soft keyboard (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, custom-component

I'm attempting to create an app w/ multiple activities that monitors different aspects of the user's interaction w/ the device. One of the main aspects is text input from a custom keyboard. I have looked at several different examples online, but none seem to work properly for me. Unfortunately, when I attempt to display the keyboard in my activity, it looks like this: http://puu.sh/jHQFQ/123ddd742b.jpg. I honestly have no idea why this happens.

Here is my keyboard: `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
        <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
        <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
        <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
        <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
        <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
        <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
        <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
        <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:horizontalGap="5%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="s"/>
        <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="d"/>
        <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="f"/>
        <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="g"/>
        <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="h"/>
        <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="j"/>
        <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="k"/>
        <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="l" android:horizontalGap="5%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyLabel="\u21E7" android:keyWidth="15%p" android:isModifier="true" android:isSticky="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="122" android:keyLabel="z"/>
        <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x"/>
        <Key android:codes="99" android:keyLabel="c"/>
        <Key android:codes="118" android:keyLabel="v"/>
        <Key android:codes="98" android:keyLabel="b"/>
        <Key android:codes="110" android:keyLabel="n"/>
        <Key android:codes="109" android:keyLabel="m"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyLabel="\u232B" android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    </Row>

    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyLabel="\u2328" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="44" android:keyLabel="," android:keyWidth="15%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="\u2334" android:keyWidth="30%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="." android:keyWidth="15%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="13" android:keyLabel="\u21B5" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

`Here is my layout:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.scsu.compsci.securityapp.Mod1_1">

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textImeMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/userInput"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:onClick="toggleKeyboard" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/question"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next_button"
        android:id="@+id/nextMod1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:onClick="mod5"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <requestFocus
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="581dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`And here is the Java file:`

```
package com.scsu.compsci.securityapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Mod1_1 extends Activity implements View.OnKeyListener, KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    EditText enterText;
    AlertDialog alert;
    Button next;
    Keyboard keys;
    KeyboardView keysView;
    boolean shift;
    long timeDown;
    long timeUp;
    long timeHold;
    long timeInterval;
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> module1_1;
    public static ArrayList<String> keyDown;
    public static ArrayList<String> keyUp;
    public static ArrayList<String> keyHold;
    public static ArrayList<String> keyInterval;
    public static ArrayList<String> keySequence;
    public static ArrayList<String> tapSize;
    public static ArrayList<String> tapPressure;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mod1_1);

        enterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextMod1);
        shift = false;

        module1_1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        keyDown = new ArrayList<String>();
        keyUp = new ArrayList<String>();
        keyHold = new ArrayList<String>();
        keyInterval = new ArrayList<String>();
        keySequence = new ArrayList<String>();
        tapSize = new ArrayList<String>();
        tapPressure = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Create the keyboard
        keys = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard);
        keysView = (KeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard);
        keysView.setKeyboard(keys);
        keysView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
        keysView.setOnKeyListener(this);
        keysView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        keysView.bringToFront();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mod1_1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
        timeDown = System.nanoTime();
        timeHold = System.nanoTime();
//        timeInterval = System.nanoTime() - timeInterval;
        if (timeInterval != 0)
            keyInterval.add(Long.toString(System.nanoTime() - timeInterval));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
//        timeUp = System.nanoTime() - timeUp;
        keyUp.add(Long.toString(System.nanoTime() - timeUp));
//        timeHold = System.nanoTime() - timeHold;
        keyHold.add(Long.toString(System.nanoTime() - timeHold));
        timeInterval = System.nanoTime();
    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
//        timeDown = System.nanoTime() - timeDown;
        keyDown.add(Long.toString(System.nanoTime() - timeDown));
        timeUp = System.nanoTime();
        keySequence.add(Integer.toString(primaryCode));

        switch(primaryCode) {
            case -1:
                shift = !shift;
                keys.setShifted(shift);
                keysView.invalidateAllKeys();
                break;
            case -4:
                keysView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                keysView.setEnabled(false);
                next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            default:
                char c = (char) primaryCode;
                if (Character.isLetter(c) && shift)
                    c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
                enterText.append(Character.toString(c));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {

    }

    public void toggleKeyboard(View view) {
        keysView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        keysView.setEnabled(true);
        if (view != null)
            ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    public void mod5(View view) {
        module1_1.add(0, keyDown);
        module1_1.add(1, keyUp);
        module1_1.add(2, keyHold);
        module1_1.add(3, keyInterval);
        module1_1.add(4, keySequence);
//        module1.add(5, tapSize);
//        module1.add(6, tapPressure);
        MainActivity.user.add(1, module1_1);
        // create Mod1_2
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mod5.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

`
I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 running 5.0 (Lollipop). Bear in mind that I have only been a programmer for a year and I taught myself how to develop for Android only 3 months ago. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you not close properly the tag Keyboard.

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
```

Should be written:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:horizontalGap="0px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Xbalanqué answer, try to set the keyHeight in the Keyboard tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:keyHeight="10%p"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:horizontalGap="0px">
```